# Get Nearby venue in Foursquare api not working in iOS 9 beta

Tags: ios, security, ssl, foursquare, ios9

In my current app, i am showing nearby venue list using foursquare api. It is working perfectly in current app till iOS 8.4.

but when i upgrade my device to iOS 9 developer release. And when i trying to fetch nearby venues that it is showing me error like

> Request
>       -------
>       curl -X GET 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_secret=XXXX&limit=50&client_id=XXXX&ll=23.034048%2C72.510689&v=201509252&radius=804',
>   [The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting
>   to a server that is pretending to be “api.foursquare.com” which could
>   put your confidential information at risk.]
>
> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this
>   server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is
>   pretending to be “api.foursquare.com” which could put your
>   confidential information at risk."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is
>   invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be
>   “api.foursquare.com” which could put your confidential information at
>   risk., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the
>   server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x16ff85c0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork
>   Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be
>   connecting to a server that is pretending to be “api.foursquare.com”
>   which could put your confidential information at risk."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is
>   invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be
>   “api.foursquare.com” which could put your confidential information at
>   risk., _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9813,
>   _kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
>   anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813,
>   kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates={type = immutable, count = 2, values = (     0 :
>      1 :
>    )},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_secret=XXXX&limit=50&client_id=XXXX&ll=23.034048%2C72.510689&v=201509252&radius=804

Can anyone suggest how to solve this issue?

FYI: i am using foursquarekit with UXRBaseNetworking Engine.

I am also getting error while check their foursquare demo name "Foursquare2"

The error is:

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
```

Comment: see this link may be help with you https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html

Comment: hey, was the issue solved??

Comment: is your issue solved ????

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```